# How to install turtlesim under Fuerte?

Tags: ros, desktop-full, ros-fuerte, beginner-tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A colleague of mine is in the process of learning ROS and he has encountered something odd in the [Understanding ROS Nodes](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingNodes) tutorial. Specifically step 1.1 Prerequisites instructs him to install the turtlesim. However when he executes the provided instruction he receives an error.

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-turtlesim
[sudo] password for matt: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-fuerte-turtlesim
```

How is the turtlesim tutorial stuff supposed to be installed under Fuerte?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48768/how-to-install-turtlesim-under-fuerte?/) by [Dustin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1938/dustin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 328 on 2012-11-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try installing `ros-fuerte-ros-tutorial`. According to http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlesim?distro=fuerte, turtlesim should be within that stack.

Update:
Too late. ;) Verifying before posting took too long...
Glad you solved it.

---

Originally posted by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) with karma: 2510 on 2012-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dustin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1938/dustin/) on 2012-11-24**:
No problem. I am changing my accepted answer to your so that you get some credit for trying. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the turtlesim tutorial material is now in the ros--ros-tutorials package.

---

Originally posted by [Dustin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1938/dustin/) with karma: 328 on 2012-11-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1